# Code jump to the error statement insist of the creating the account in registration app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a registration Activity in my android application when I compile it runs without and error it seems like there is a logical problem when I run my application instant of creating a new account it jumps to the error code as I have provided my registration activity code in the in method creatnewAccount() in the if statement where I have tried to check whether the rpassword and the password are same. Whenever I run my application and enter the detail and click signup button it jumps to the else statement. Can't understand what's the error and what should I do

```
   package com.nanb.chaton;

   import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

   import android.app.ProgressDialog;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.text.TextUtils;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
   import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
   import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
   import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

   import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText Email, Password, Repassword;
private Button Signup, Login;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ProgressDialog lodingBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    rimplemantaion();
    sendusertoLogin();
    createAccount();
}

private void createAccount() {
    Signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            createnewAccount();
        }
    });
}

private void createnewAccount() {
    String email = Email.getText().toString();
    String password = Password.getText().toString();
    String rpassword = Repassword.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email i'd ", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Password ", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rpassword)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Re-Password ", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (rpassword == password ){
        lodingBar.setTitle("Creating new account");
        lodingBar.setMessage("Pleased wait till we creat your account");
        lodingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        lodingBar.show();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    sendusertoLogin();
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Account created succcessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    lodingBar.dismiss();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Sorry,There is a problem while creating your accout. Please try again later", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    lodingBar.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password and Re-enter password are not same ", LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}

private void sendusertoLogin() {
    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
        }
    });
}

private void rimplemantaion() {
    Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    Repassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rpassword);
    Signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUp);
    Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogIn);
    lodingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
}
}
```

Comment: please dont use == for string comparison, Instead use if(rpassword.equals(password)) for string comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace  this

```
if (rpassword == password ){

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password and Re-enter password are not same ", LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

with this

```
 if (rpassword.equals(password) ){

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password and Re-enter password are not same ", LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked but still  when I run my app and try to register a new account but the new account is not been created can you identify the error